# Elementary group theory question

Tags: automorphism-groups

Is the following statement true in general?

If $G$ is any group and $K(G)=\{x \in G ; \alpha(x)=x , \forall \alpha \in Aut_c(G)\}$ when $Aut_c(G)$ is the subgroup of all central automorphisms. Then $Aut_c(K(G))=<1>$.

Comment: What's the motivation for the question? E.g., did you carry out computations for a lot of small groups and find such a statement to hold for them? (I'd be surprised if this is true for all finite groups...)

Answer (score 2):

Take $G$ to be the nonabelian group of exponent $3$ and order $27$.  Then the inner automorphisms are self-centralizing in $Aut(G)$, so $K(G)$ is just $Z(G)$, a group of order $3$.  Thus $Aut_c(K(G))=Aut(K(G))\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, the statement fails for any finite nonabelian $p$-group, $p>2$. Indeed, $\operatorname{Aut}_cG=\hom(G/G',Z(G))\ne0$ for any $p$-group $G$. Besides, it also follows that $K(G)\supset G'$ and, if $G$ is a $p$-group, so is $K(G)$. This looks like a homework.

Comment: I believe a *central automorphism* is one that commutes with all inner automorphisms.  So for example the OP's statement is true for $D_8$.

Comment: Indeed, Alex' argument is perfectly correct except when $G_{ab}\cong Z(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, for stupid reasons.  In that case $Aut_c(G)=Aut_c(K)=\{1\} $.